# GnuPG Domain to Domain email encryption

Tags: email, encryption, domain, gnupg, pgp

I'm running a Debian mail server and am looking forward to encrypt mails from my domain to the domain of a business partner. Also, the encryption should happen on the mail server itself not on a mail client.

Is this possible? I already found out how to create a key that has the mail address "@domain.com", but I can't use it on our mail client, since it doesn't support GnuPG or PGP.

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off with enforcing TLS for the connection between your mailservers.

Comment: Exactly, tls, ssh, if they're both servers under your control they're just transferred data into mailboxes, why bother with gpg? ***OR*** is the question not fully explained...?

Answer (score 2):

### Encrypting Mail Transfer Agents

It is well possible what you're trying to achieve, but you'll need to install additional software, a so-called "encrypting MTA" (mail transfer agent, also known as mail server).

There are several products available, [G10code's GEAM](http://g10code.com/p-geam.html) (from the company developing GnuPG), [Symantec's Gateway Email Encryption](http://www.symantec.com/gateway-email-encryption/?fid=encryption) and probably even more. There are different scenarios, defining a single key for all messages, storing different keys on the server for each of the users/mail boxes.

### Transfer Encryption

But the scenario you're describing is *transfer encryption*, as only the transmission of the messages is to be protected, not the processing or storage of the mails (the servers must do the encryption tasks anyway, if the client applications should not do it). Both OpenPGP or S/MIME are the wrong tools for transfer encryption, they're meant for encrypting individual messages. This has both advantages and disadvantages; in the case of misusing them for your scenario this means some meta data is still unencrypted (recipients, subject lines, ...), and implementing this requires additional software and is more complicated to use compared to protocols build for this prupose.

What you probably should look into is encrypting the communication in-between the servers. Configure both of them properly to support TLS, and consider enforcing TLS connections to the respective other server. This will encrypt *all* communication in-between those servers including meta data, and is supported out of the box by all relevant mail server implementations, and finally also will transparently encrypt communication with other mail servers if possible.

Transfer encryption should be something you implement anyway, and depending on the local legislation something actually required as you process personal information and communication (but often nobody cares, and completely denying unencrypted communication with arbitrary mail servers would prevent communication with some peers).

### Message Encryption

It still might be important to encrypt messages on the clients. If OpenPGP is out of scope (because of installing additional software, and it might also happen OpenPGP just isn't the best tool to use for this use case), consider having a look at S/MIME, which is natively supported by most mail clients.